# Conversions between object types

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

What I'm trying to do:

```
void startApp() {
            //create validator
        MedValidator* val = new MedValidator();
        //create reporsitory
        MedicineRepository* repo= new MedRepo() ;
        //create controller
        Control wh(repo, val);
    ...}
```

Here is a view at the used types:

```
 class MedValidator
    {
    public:
        void validate(const Medicine& s) throw(MedException);
    };


class MedicineRepository
{
public: virtual void addMed(Medicine s) ;
};

class MedRepo : public MedicineRepository{
public:void addMed(Medicine s);
protected:
    Vector<Medicine*> MedList;
};
```

I get `Multiple markers at this line
    - candidates are:
    - no matching function for call to 'Control::Control(MedicineRepository&, 
     MedValidator*&)'` at `startApp()` when I'm declaring `wh`

```
class Control {
public:
    Control(MedRepo* repo, MedValidator* validator);};
```

How can I fix this?I hope the amount of code is enough,if it's needed more I'll add.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor for `Control` takes a `MedRepo*` argument:

```
Control(MedRepo* repo, MedValidator* validator);};
```

But you are passing a `MedicineRepository*`:

```
 MedicineRepository* repo= new MedRepo() ;
 //create controller
 Control wh(repo, val);
```

Also, don't use exception specifications, they're [bad](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm).

Comment: Ok,but if I'm switching them into `MedRepo* repo= new MedicineRepository() ;`I get a new error `invalid conversion from 'MedicineRepository*' to 'MedRepo*' [-fpermissive]`

Comment: Whilst `MedicineRepository* repo= new MedRepo() ;` is fine because `MedicineRepository` is a base class of `MedRepo`, `MedRepo* repo= new MedicineRepository()` is not because there is no implicit conversion from `MedicineRepository` to `MedRepo`.

Comment: So what you we're telling me was to modify ` Control(MedRepo* repo, MedValidator* validator);` in  `Control(MedicineRepository* repo, MedValidator* validator);` ,right?

Comment: Doing that is a good way to solve this issue if what your objective is for `Control` to use the interface of `MedicineRepository`. That way, you can still pass types derived from `MedicineRepository`, such as `MedRepo`, that implement the member functions differently.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that MedRepo is a MedicineRepository but MedicineRepository is not a MedRepo. You can't substitute a base class object where a derived class object is expected, only the reverse (safely, anyway). You need to figure out if you need a pointer to that specific derived class or if a pointer to any derived class is okay. For the former keep your code how it is and send it a MedRepo object. If any derived class will do (i.e. you're only accessing methods from the base class) then change Control to accept the base class instead.